# date is back flowed in java application

Tags: java, date

i was used date in thread.

but sometimes, the date is back flowed.

this is sample code.

```
private class Test extends Thread
{
   private DateFormat _dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

   public Test()
   {
      // Start Thread
   }

   private void Print(Date date)
   {
      System.out.println("<TIME>" + _dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "");
   }

   public void run()
   {
      // Works In Thread.
      Print(new Date());
      Print(new Date());
   }
}
```

what's wrong of this?

Result:

```
<TIME>2018-11-13 05:02:16.860</TIME>
<TIME>2018-11-13 05:01:58.235</TIME>
```

Comment: What is `back flowed`? I don't believe that is a valid word.

Comment: As per the Javadocs *Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.*

Comment: Your screenshot does not correspond to your code. When I run your code (with a simple main method), I do not get your result. So please, make an [mcve].

Comment: thread works asynchronously, not at the same time, so it might be like first thread got the time first and after some time second thread also got its time, but while printing those timings second thread executed first and then first thread prints the timing.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I know, but I can't find the def of what it means, I am not a native english speaker.

Comment: @SamzSakerz I think he means `back-to-front`

Comment: @ScaryWombat That doesn't make sense either to what he is trying to say lol

Comment: @KyungjoonLee Regarding your post: make sure to always post console output as text instead of an image. Regarding your code: make sure you follow the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.google.nl/search?q=java+naming+conventions): method and variable names are written in camelCase, that means starting with lowercase and no underscores. Furthermore, I suggest you drop the usage of `Date` and `Calendar` classes, and start using the new Date and Time API from the `java.time` package. That *might* also eliminate your problem, since all `java.time` classes are thread-safe.

Comment: @SamzSakerz The noun *[backflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backflow)* is apparently used as a verb.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one error and a concept related to threads:

1. With `Print(new Date());` , you are creating a new Date, but you are not using that: in fact you are creating a new one `_dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "")` : you should use the one that you are passing in the constructor, or simply don't pass that as argument if you are not using it.
2. You are working with threads: you don't know which thread is running as first (they are asynchronous) : most probably , in your example, the first run has ended after the second. Try adding a name to your thread and print that , this will helps you understanding which print is related to which thread

Answer (score 1):

`Date` uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` which uses your "wall clock".  This wall clock is not guaranteed to by monotonically increasing, but is instead adjusted to match the best clocks on the internet it can access e.g. via NTP.

16 seconds is a pretty big jump in time, so I would look at how your NTP is setup. Normally, NTP tries to smooth out its corrections but it can be forced to jump to a particular time immediately.

NOTE: While race conditions between threads could cause this behaviour, it's unlikely to cause a 16 second jump in time like this.

To solve the race condition, you can hold the lock on `System.out` to ensure you don't have concurrent attempts to write the output.

```
private void printTime() {
     synchronized(System.out) {
        System.out.println("<TIME>" + _dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "</TIME>");
    }
}
```